# ContextMenuStrip text alignment C#

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip, text-alignment

Hi
Does anybody know how we can align the text in the ContextMenuStrip (in WinForms) to the center?
thanks!

Comment: You probably won't like this question, but *why would you ever want to do that?* Every other menu in the system (unless you're using a `RightToLeft` layout) has the text on the left and the shortcut on the right.

Comment: @Cody Gray Because you are trying to emulate an already twisted UI that already shows the menus this way? Let's say for example, an Alenia Marconi ATC RADAR UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement custom `ToolStripRenderer` (use one of 2 standard to minimize code):

```
public sealed class CustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
{
    protected override void OnRenderItemText(ToolStripItemTextRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Item.IsOnDropDown)
        {
            e.TextFormat |= TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter;
        }
        base.OnRenderItemText(e);
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
ToolStripManager.Renderer = new CustomRenderer();
```

Note though that this is not standard Windows GUI menu item layout which users expect.

Comment: +1 because this works. And an implied +5 for noting this is not what users expect.