# C# ToolStripItem needs to be right-aligned and also RightToLeft.No

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a drop-down menu that consists of a combination of numbers and words:

```
1 Minute
5 Minutes
10 Minutes
```

I want this menu to be right aligned.  Here is the code:

```
ToolStripMenuItem Item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
Item.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No;
Item.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

However, this doesn't work.  If I change the `RightToLeft` attribute to `Yes` then it becomes right-aligned, but then the number appears on the right of list.

```
  Minute 1 
 Minutes 5 
Minutes 10
```

How do I get both `RightToLeft.No` and `ContentAlignment.MiddleRight`?

```
  1 Minute  
 5 Minutes  
10 Minutes
```

Comment: See [ContextMenuStrip text alignment C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4397655/719186)

Comment: The ContextMenuStrip is a shortcut menu to display when the user right-clicks the control.  This is not what I need for text alignment when the user left-clicks the menu.

Comment: MenuStrips and ContextMenuStrips both use ToolStripMenuItems, so same thing.